# Agenda del sitio

Tags: discusión

He encontrado que este sitio tiene implícitamente una política y una mentalidad bastante nocivas para el español. No se pueden hacer preguntas "culturales" o "políticas", más bien, consiste básicamente en un muro donde pegar artículos o citas obtenidos de alguna fuente externa. El español es una lengua que - aunque no se quiera así pensar -  no acepta una única fuente de verdad, ni una única autoridad. Al contrario, he visto como en este sitio aquello que esté registrado en cualquier documento de la RAE es ya un hecho. ¿No sería mejor, entonces, ir directamente a buscar esos documentos uno mismo?

Inicialmente consideré este sitio como una plataforma constructiva donde compartir conocimiento y opiniones con otros hispanohablantes, pero me doy cuenta que es simplemente la extensión de la mentalidad de unos que son "dueños" del español y que hay temas que "sí tienen que ver con el español y otros no", y que esos dueños deciden cuáles son.

Comment: Lerdonia, ¿podrías poner algunos ejemplos de preguntas que se cerraron por el motivo que señalaste?  En cuanto al gran peso que se da a la RAE, he notado lo mismo; sin embargo cuando ofrezco otras fuentes, por lo general encuentro una actitud abierta a considerarlas.  Una cosa que hay que tomar en cuenta es que esta no es una época de mucho tráfico en el sitio.  Hay buena gente aquí, espero que nos dés otro chance.

Comment: Voting to reopen, even though I agree the question needs examples.  Reason for voting to reopen despite the lack of examples: the question has a well-received answer.

Comment: @aparente001 _A question that is closed, even if it has one or more high quality answers, should not be re-opened unless it has been edited to address the issue(s) that led to its closure_ ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292373/209901))

Comment: @fedorqui - But we're in Meta here.  I agree, in general terms, when it comes to the factual character of the main site.  (Although note that I have seen cases, *very* occasionally on other SE sites, where community consensus determined that the question had been closed erroneously.) // I'm not saying you or anybody else *has* to join me in voting to reopen; I'm just saying that it is not unreasonable to vote to reopen this.

Comment: Imagine yourself in OP's shoes in some other SE site that you become interested in. Imagine that you feel completely disgusted by the culture and tone of the site and you post your specific criticisms of how you think the site is not reflecting the original intent of the SE system. In frustration, you post at Meta  -- the appropriate place to express thsse frustrations.  And then you get shut down there too!  Not just downvoted.  Your question gets *closed*!  What does that tell you about the site? That those people are incapable of *listening*.

Answer (score 3):

En mi modesta (y personal) opinión, creo que la política del sitio es hacer preguntas y obtener respuestas sobre el **idioma español (o castellano)**, y por eso se llama **Spanish Language**. En [What topics can I ask about here? / ¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) viene un esquema de lo que la comunidad a lo largo del tiempo ha decidido que se puede y no se puede preguntar:

> ### ¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?
>
> **Spanish Language Stack Exchange** es para lingüistas,
>   docentes, estudiantes y entusiastas en general del idioma español. Las
>   preguntas sobre los siguientes asuntos son bienvenidas:
>
> - Lingüística (fonética, fonología, morfología, sintaxis, semántica, pragmática)
>
>   Ortografía (acentos, puntuación, guiones, mayúsculas)
>
>   Etimología (historia del desarrollo de las palabras)
>
>   Traducción de cierta expresión o concepto *al español* (pero recuerda que debes indicar qué has intentado)
>
>   Diferencias dialécticas
>
>   Usos, elección de palabras, gramática y pronunciación
>
>   Problemas encontrados por la gente que está aprendiendo español
>
> Pero por favor, no preguntes sobre los siguientes asuntos. Están
>   fuera del ámbito de este sitio.
>
> - Por favor, corrige mi documento ("¿hay algún error en este texto?").
>
>   Otros idiomas diferentes del español (incluyendo traducciones del español a otros idiomas).
>
>   Cómo mejorar mi español.
>
>   Crítica, discusión o análisis de literatura española.
>
>   Quejas sobre la gramática disfrazadas de preguntas.
>
>   "Explicadme este chiste", excepto en el caso donde el punto esencial del chiste se basa en un aspecto del español cubierto en uno
>     de los asuntos válidos indicados anteriormente.
>
>   Preguntas sobre "listas", donde cada respuesta es igualmente válida.
>
>   Preguntas sobre la cultura que no se relacionan directamente con el idioma español.

No estoy muy seguro, pero quizás las preguntas / respuestas sobre **historia** deberían ir a https://history.stackexchange.com/, las de **política** a https://politics.stackexchange.com/. Sobre las cuestiones culturales, ni idea.

En otro orden de cosas, la DRAE, por lo que he visto, no es "la autoridad suprema": hay muchas preguntas referentes a palabras o significados no incluidos en el Diccionario de la Lengua Española, sobre americanismos, sobre etimología e historia de palabras, etc. Por poner algún ejemplo: [¿Por qué "enturcado" quiere decir enfadado en Nicaragua?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26503/por-qu%C3%A9-enturcado-quiere-decir-enfadado-en-nicaragua), [¿Por qué en español decimos "zorro" en vez de un derivado del latín "vulpes"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26494/por-qu%C3%A9-en-espa%C3%B1ol-decimos-zorro-en-vez-de-un-derivado-del-lat%C3%ADn-vulpes) o [Uso de "vianda" en Puerto Rico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26482/uso-de-vianda-en-puerto-rico). Algunas respuestas se basan en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia), en [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/), en libros encontrados buscando a través de Google Books, diccionarios como el etimológico de Corominas, blogs de internet como [Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/), etc. Y a veces, ni eso (por ejemplo, en la segunda respuesta a [¿Modismo para "drinking from the firehose"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19812/modismo-para-drinking-from-the-firehose)), pero en general parece preferirse que haya algún tipo de respaldo mejor que simples opiniones.

En resumen: las preguntas y respuestas deben ser **sobre el idioma**; las cuestiones culturales y políticas parecen estar fuera del ámbito **por definición**.

Comment: Además, creo que muchos (yo, por ejemplo, lo he hecho varias veces) incluso al citarlas, hemos discrepado con lo que dicen las obras de la ASALE, de la cual la RAE es miembro.  No es frecuente pero vamos, acaece.  En general en las obras más densas y profundas de la ASALE, sus autores reconocen cualquier tipo de desacuerdo entre académicos y lingüistas.